# Running Sphinx via tox

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, tox

I have a tox configuration that allows me to run some checks on documentation. This is more or less from the [official documentation on tox](http://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/jenkins.html#integrating-sphinx-documentation-checks-in-a-jenkins-job).

```
[tox]
envlist = py36, flake8, docs

[testenv:docs]
basepython=python3.6
changedir=docs  # ← causes sphinx-apidoc to misbehave.
deps=-r{toxinidir}/requirements/requirements.txt
commands=
    sphinx-apidoc --force --separate --private --module-first -o docs site '*/*test*' '*/*migration*'
    pytest --maxfail=1 --tb=line -v --junitxml=junit_{envname}.xml check_sphinx.py
```

However, the first command (`sphinx-apidoc …`) needs to the run in the root of the project otherwise the exclude patterns do not work. This is despite me trying many possible variations. The second command needs to be run within the `docs` directory.

*How can I have both commands run in separate directories?*

Answer (score 3):

Point `commands` to a shell script, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eux

sphinx-apidoc --force --separate --private --module-first -o docs site '*/*test*' '*/*migration*'
cd docs
pytest --maxfail=1 --tb=line -v --junitxml=junit_{envname}.xml check_sphinx.py
```